# Requirement: Trigger On Account

Tags: apex, trigger, controller, visualforce-component

Requirement: **Trigger On Account.**
For associated contacts for any Account ,i need to check Last_Response_Date in Contact and for the contact whose Last_Response_Date is latest ,i need to update a field of that contact(response_Need-check box) to true.
 I am new to Apex .Please help to get this solved.

I started with something like below

```
trigger AccContactUpdate on Account (before insert,before update) {

   List<Account> acc = [SELECT Id,Name,(SELECT Id,Rsponse_send_Date__c FROM  Contacts) FROM Account where id in :trigger.new];

   List<contact>  contactList =new List<contact>();  
    system.debug('acc ---'+acc);

        for(account a:acc){
            contactList.add(a.Contacts);

 }
         system.debug('contactList ---'+contactList );


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to simply change you query on accounts by adding `ORDER BY` clause:

```
[SELECT Id,Name,
               (SELECT Id,Rsponse_send_Date__c 
                FROM  Contacts 
                ORDER BY Rsponse_send_Date__c DESC
                LIMIT 1) 
FROM Account 
WHERE id in :trigger.new];
```

The first record in Contacts would have the latest `Rsponse_send_Date__c`